# How to import function from file inside a for loop in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have a lot of files and each file contains one function, I have to import all the functions. I have file names in a string, how can I do that inside a loop in python2.7

Ex - file1 abc.py -> this contains abc function
file2 xyz.py -> this contains xyz function

Comment: Please check my answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for f in ['abc.py', ..., 'xyz.py']:
    exec(open(f).read())
```

`exec` will execute the given `str`ing as Python code.

If you do

```
for m in ['abc', ..., 'xyz']:
    exec('import ' + m)
```

your files are `import`ed as modules, however, inside a scope of each `for` loop. So you cannot use functions outside the loop.